# Show empty cell value for datetime field in Kendo grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid where I have added a column of DateTime type which shows datetime.

The problem which I am facing is that if their is no date set then by default it is showing `null` value.

What I want is that if no date is set then it should show blank cell value instead of null.

I am using `2012.2.710.340` version of kendo.

Have declare the field value in class in following way :

```
public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
```

Below is the format I have used in kendo grid to show datetime field in grid :

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Time).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}").Title("Time");
```

I will be thankful if anyone could help me out in solving my problem.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried using kendo.tostring in following way:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Time).ClientTemplate("#= (Time == null) ? ' ' : kendo.toString(Time, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') #").Title("Time");
```

By applying the above code my problem gets solved but because of this filters in the kendo grid stop working. I want that filters should work inspite of having blank value for datetime field in the grid if datetime is not set.

Comment: For dates that cannot be nulled, use (Time) check instead of (Time == null)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
columns.Bound(o => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.Time)?string.Empty:o.Time).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}").Title("Time");
```

or use the column template to render the date.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="TimeTemplate">
     # var date = time === null ? '': time ;#
    #=date#

</script>
```

Comment: I believe this wont work becoz cant cast datetime to string this way

Answer (score 2):

```
 columns.Bound(r => r.AssignedDate).ClientTemplate("#= AssignedDateFormat(data) #").Title("Assigned Dt").Width("40px"); 

function AssignedDateFormat(param) {
    var html;
    if (param.AssignedDate == null) {
        html = ""; 
    }
    else {
        html = kendo.toString(param.AssignedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    }

    return html;
}
```